# How to convert an edge list to an adjacency matrix in SAS?

Tags: sas, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I'm a beginner using SAS to perform network analysis. The data set is represented as an edge list in a CSV file, `node1`, `node2`, weight as each column. I want to convert this data set to an adjacency matrix, but I have no idea how to do it. Is there any function that could do it?

And also, because it is a very large data set, so I wonder if there is something like `sparseMatrix` in R to convert and store it effectively?

Many thanks.

Comment: Using Base SAS, or using SAS/IML (matrix language)?

Comment: @Joe thanks, I tried IML but it requires too much memory :P the data set has about 200 thousand nodes, it said insufficient memory when I was trying to create a matrix with such number of rows and columns.

Comment: IML is the only way to really manipulate matrices in SAS.  You can obviously use some methods, but really if you're doing stuff like this you need IML. I recommend posting on communities.sas.com; Rick Wicklin likely can guide you to using IML without running into memory limits (you can).

Comment: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/01/21/reading-big-data/ for example is a good place t o start.k